# Create a variable in R dataframe recoding a variable using an external table?

Tags: r, dataframe, variables

I have a dataframe with a numeric code for the city. There is a standard table for conversion from code to city name. I created another dataframe with these codes. How to create a new variable in the first dataframe containing the name of the city by comparing the numeric codes in the two different data frames?

Example:

DF1 is a dataframe and contains the variable IBGE.
DF2 is another dataframe and contains the variable IBGE (same and different values from DF1) and the variable IDH. My intention is to have a new variable IDH in DF1. For example, if IDH is 0.871 for a given IBGE in DF2, the new variable in DF1 will have the same value.

Comment: Use `merge(df1, df2, by="city_code")`.  Read [this](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/relational-data.html?q=left%20join#understanding-joins) to understand how R does joins/merges.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.